# How to run WSO2 EMM in webapp-mode?

Tags: wso2-iot

Good evening. Can somebody help me on how to run WSO2 EMM in webapp-mode? I can run the server in localhost but i want it to be a web based app. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is documented [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/General+Server+Configurations).

Comment: Thank you sir for answering. I'm using wso2 emm 1.1.0 and the documentation about the said version does not contain anything about cloud deployment.

Comment: I recommend you to use EMM 2.0 since it has lot of new features and new improvements. Clustering guide is available in https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+EMM+2.0.0

Comment: Thank you sir for answering again. What kind of server or web host I can upload the project?

Comment: And I just started the 1.1.0 version last month thats why I want to continue this version,

Comment: Can I upload the project in Openshift or any free web hosting?

Comment: Or there's no need to upload the project? All I just do is to set my domain name?

Comment: Its all included in the pack. You just have to put the pack in the sever and configure SSL, domain names etc. and start the pack. Configurations etc. is included in the documentation.